# git bash under Windows 10 doesn't execute vagrant version

Tags: windows-10, vagrant, git-bash

Installed git version 2.35.1.windows.2 under Windows 10.
From git bash, run: vagrant version. Opens up a dos window, executes, and closes.
So I cannot use these types of commands, like vagrant version.
100% repeatable.

If I run git bash elevated, then I can see the command completes as expected.

Expected behavior from a Windows 10 machine that works, with git running not elevated:

```
vagrant version
Installed Version: 2.2.19
Latest Version: 2.2.19
```

Both machines, the one that works as expected and the one that fails, git was installed as regular user, with git being installing under:
C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\git-bash.exe --cd-to-home

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as the tag states: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Comment: This is a git bash issue. It runs the command in a new window. This is the issue. vagrant version is a way to replicate, one use case that fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try, with the problematic PC, to use a simplified PATH and see if that works:

Open a CMD and type:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set "GH=%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Git"
set "PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%"
set "PATH=C:\path\to\vagrant.exe;%PATH%"
```

Replace `C:\path\to\vagrant.exe` by the *parent* folder of `vagrant.exe`, do not include `vagrant.exe` itself in the `%PATH%`.

Test if the issue persists then in that CMD session.

```sh
bash
vagrant version
```

Comment: Should clarify that git bash doesn't work, git cmd does work. Once I get access to the machine that fails, I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @Marinela With the simplified path I propose, you just type `bash` from a regular `CMD`, and you are in a git bash session.

Comment: Tried the scenario, with sets from CMD, same issue. vagrant version opens the dos window, then gets closed, but with no way to see the output. @VonC, thank you for the feedback so far.

Comment: @Marinela in the git bash session (from the CMD with simplified PATH), what does `which vagran` return? Is it a `vagran` shell script which in turn would call `vagran.exe`? Or is it directly `vagran.exe`?

Comment: it is vagrant.exe, not a script

Comment: ls -l /c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin/
total 2976
-rwxr-xr-x 1 selsetm 1049089 3045248 Nov  3 23:27 vagrant.exe*

Comment: On a system that works, I get this: file /c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin/vagrant.exe
/c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin/vagrant.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows

Comment: The programmer is gone for the weekend, I can get the same info from the machine that fails on Monday.

Comment: Could git bash be effected when running 32-bit executable? The host itself is a 64-bit machine.

Comment: @Marinela Indeed. the `vagrant_2.2.19_i686.msi` would not give a working `vagran.exe`. `vagrant_2.2.19_x86_64.msi` would work for 64-bits OS.

Comment: The published msi to install is vagrant_2.2.19_x86_64. I'll observe the system while is  installing vagrant but I think this is what the programmer did anyway.

Comment: Note that the file command on vagrant was executed from machine that works as expected.

Comment: which vagrant
/c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin/vagrant

Comment: file /c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin/vagrant
/c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin/vagrant: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows

Comment: so vagrant was installed correctly

Comment: @Marinela It does look the right version indeed. Do you see any other difference between this PC and the working PC?

Comment: Not sure where to look. I agree there is something different, just not sure what it would be. He had OneDrive installed, it was removed since. Looks like privileges issues to me. I am going to ask the developer to redo the vagrant installation and observe it while it is doing it. We already reinstalled git many times over.