# Visual studio cannot run pre/post commit hooks: /usr/bin/env 'bash': No such file or directory

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, husky

We have an existing git repository with a .Net solution. We are adding a web application to the mix. The web application(angular) is in a specific subfolder.

We did install some pre-post commit hooks, to ensure the file is properly linted. Everything works fine when committing with VS Code or Source tree. But when I try to commit something directly from Visual Studio, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/env: 'bash': No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to make it work?

For reference, here are my hooks:

**post-checkout**

```
#!/bin/sh
command -v git-lfs >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "\nThis repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting '.git/hooks/post-checkout'.\n"; exit 2; }
git lfs post-checkout "$@"
```

**post-commit**

```
#!/bin/sh
command -v git-lfs >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "\nThis repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting '.git/hooks/post-commit'.\n"; exit 2; }
git lfs post-commit "$@"
```

**post-merge**

```
#!/bin/sh
command -v git-lfs >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "\nThis repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting '.git/hooks/post-merge'.\n"; exit 2; }
git lfs post-merge "$@"

cd ./Src/Frontend
npx git-pull-run --pattern "package-lock.json" --command "npm install"
```

**pre-commit**

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

cd ./Src/Frontend
npm run lint
```

**pre-push**

```
#!/bin/sh
command -v git-lfs >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "\nThis repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting '.git/hooks/pre-push'.\n"; exit 2; }
git lfs pre-push "$@"
```

There has to be a way of using to pre/post commit hooks while still being able to commit in VS Code and VS, right? What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your `%PATH%` first, which should include `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`, where `bash.exe` resides.

Or modify, for testing, the [shebang directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang) with:

```
#!C:/Program\ Files/Git/git-bash.exe
```

---

[J4v4scr1pt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3727466/j4v4scr1pt) adds in the comments:

- having found [how to set environment variables](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)
- adding what [typicode/husky issue 1038](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/1038) suggests

  > Just add `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\cygpath.exe` to you `PATH` environment variable and it should work perfectly
- stating:

  > I added "`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\`" to the "`User variables for userName`" where "`/usr/`" did the trick.
  > And I needed to restart VS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It appears that currently, I've C:\Program files\Git\cmd in my PATH, but not the bin.  Since git.exe is present in both cmd and bin directory, which one should be specified first?

Comment: @J4N Both include the same git.exe, so it does not matter. I usually set bin first, then cmd. And also `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core` because of the `git-credential-manager-core.exe` used for HTTPS authentication (from the [GCM project](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager))

Comment: I added the path after the cmd, restarted VS and it works. I think I was already using the git-credential-manager-core before, so probably it was already in my path. Thank you!

Comment: @J4N OK, well done.

Comment: @J4v4Scr1pt Example of PATH setting (on Windows): "[`git bash` under Windows 10 doesn't execute `vagrant version`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71881614/6309)".

Comment: Thx @VonC! I managed to find where I can edit path thro enviroment varibles.
And added what they suggest in this thread:
https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/1038

This changed the error to be "Current directory is not a git directory!"

Comment: From the logs: 
Error: command failed
verbose stack    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)

Comment: Ok I know I'm spamming this thread now but just to clearify how I solved this:
I added "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\" to the "User variables for userName" where  "/usr/" did the trick. And I needed to restart VS.
Maybe this will help someone. And again @VonC thx for the help :)

Comment: @J4v4Scr1pt Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comments and findings in the answer for more visibility.