# openssl command fail on one windows machine in GitBash window while works on another

Tags: windows, openssl, git-bash

This command fails on one Windows machine in git bash session, while on the other machine it work fine.

```
auser@pc MINGW64 /c/Developer/TEMP/openssltest
$ echo "Hi Alice!" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey /c/Developer/TEMP/openssltest/pub2.pem --pubin
Can't open /c/Developer/TEMP/openssltest/pub2.pem for reading, No such file or directory
15844:error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process:../openssl-1.1.1k/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('/c/Developer/TEMP/openssltest/pub2.pem','r')
15844:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../openssl-1.1.1k/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:
unable to load Public Key

auser@pc
```

This command work on a machine where it fails

```
$ echo "Hi Alice!" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey ./pub2.pem --pubin
```

I do not have any issues on another machine. Where to look?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into:

- difference in openssl version
- read access: `cat /c/Developer/TEMP/openssltest/pub2.pem` (or `cat /c/Developer/TEMP/anyOtherFile`)
- difference in user for the shell session (`env|grep -i user`)

If you are running that test with a user account which does not have the right to read that `TEMP` folder, you would get that error.

Comment: openssl were different. copied from working machine to machine where it doesn't work and still same problem. File access permission checked and file can be read. Moreover it works if execute in the same directory: echo "Hi Alice!" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey ./pub2.pem --pubin

Comment: @AlexK Does it work from a git bash session or a regular CMD one?

Comment: @AlexK Instead of copying just openssl.exe, I would upgrade Git itsefl to use the same version (assuming you are *not* using a `C:\Windows\System32` openssl one). Check what `where openssl` returns.

Comment: Git upgrading was not an option as this is closed environment. I can not install git, it was coming from Visual Studio. openssl identified with `which openssl`, what returned /minigw64/bin/openssl. I'd like to stress again it is able to read public key if you execute command in the same folder where the file and just specify `pub2.pem`. If you specify full path it doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexK Git does not have to be "installed": you can uncompress it anywhere you want, and adjust your PATH, using [`PortableGit-2.36.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.36.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.36.1-64-bit.7z.exe). It is better to use the new openssl in the context of a full Git distro, rather than trying and copying just one exe.

Comment: > Does it work from a git bash session or a regular CMD one?
@VonC it worked from git bash if you're in the directory in which file is located and I used just file name. Today it stopped to work even from local folder. Seems your security team decided to tight it more. I send email explaining that their measures preventing me getting my encrypted AzDO PAT tokens.

Comment: @AlexK OK. Again, nothing prevents you to try with the latest version of Git, [using your own PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71881614/6309).